# Snowflake stage creation with relative path

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I'm trying to use the "test" folder name as dynamic folder path for Snowflake stage creation, which comes after the s3 url.

Copy command runs but returns zero records.

```
  create or replace stage MYSQL_S3 url='s3://myproject/product/BackEnd/'
  credentials=(aws_key_id='x' aws_secret_key='s' AWS_TOKEN='s')
  file_format = myformat.format_csv;


 copy into test from @MYSQL_S3 pattern = 'test/'
```

Anything is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pattern='.*test/.*'`.  [Pattern](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching) is a regex and has to match the path (S3 key) and the filename.  You can use [LIST](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/list.html) to see what the pattern is matching.

Or to append `test/` to the stage url, try `copy into test from @MYSQL_S3/test/;`

Comment: any work around for this type 'copy into test from @MYSQL_S3/test/;' ?

Comment: Glad the regex is working.  Are you trying to to get `@MYSQL_S3/test/` to resolve to `s3://myproject/product/BackEnd/test/`?  If so, please try removing the trailing slash in your url when you create the stage.  That may be resulting in two slashes in the path.